# void function not returning

Tags: return, void

I am having an issue returning out of  a void function.

I can see the output printed when the name (input) is found, which returns true. The void function should return if the lambda (or name_checker) function returns true, but it still implementing remaining part of the function.

Comment: If the node is a `ControlNode`, the function will not return until it has iterated over, and recursed into, all the children. It is common to return a value that indicates success so you can avoid pointless recursions.

Comment: How do you know it's still implementing the rest of the function? Because, clearly, you are mistaken about that. Maybe you are confusing the rest of the function, with remaining recursive calls to your function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function to return a `bool`, use that return value to quit immediately that you find something. Something like this

```
bool findTreeNodeRecursively(unsigned indent, const TreeNode* node, const std::function<bool(const TreeNode*)>& name_checker){

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < indent; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "   ";
    }
    if (!node)
    {
        std::cout << "!nullptr!" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    indent++;

    if(name_checker(node) == true){
        return true;
    }

    if (auto control = dynamic_cast<const ControlNode*>(node))
    {
        for (const auto& child : control->children())
        {
            if (findTreeNodeRecursively(indent, child, name_checker))
                return true;
        }
    }
    else if (auto decorator = dynamic_cast<const DecoratorNode*>(node))
    {
        if (findTreeNodeRecursively(indent, decorator->child(), name_checker))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In a recursive function `return` only returns from one recursive call, it doesn't return all the way back to the top. If that's what you want you have to program it.

Comment: that works! thank you very much for your explanation and help!